# Call Center Headset Recommendations

Tags: voip

We have a call center with roughly 32 agents and bought the Sennheiser PC136 USB headsets for our agents use.  We have had a lot more issues with the headsets then I anticipated.  Most of the issues seem to be centered around no audio issues.  This seems to be a function of the USB adapter going "bad" or possibly the VOIP phone software we are using (Sipek2).  Anyone in a call center environment have recommendations for a good headset that can take abuse and just generally perform well?  Thanks guys and gals.

Comment: Better suited to Server Fault?

Comment: I'd say this belongs on superuser, but well...

Answer (score 4):

Plantronics models all seem to stand up well to a lot of use. I haven't used one for the last couple of years, and can't recommend anything specific anymore.

Comment: Many years ago I used what looks like the encore series from Plantronics.  I've had both the single and dual headphone, the former being suited for quieter environments.  Pricey, but very durable and good quality.  There is a reason they cost what they do.

Answer (score 3):

I have used a **Plantronics H251 SupraPlus** a lot and I own a **Sennheiser PC146** for use at home.
While the PC145 is definitely a good headset the difference is still huge.

---

What is cool about the Plantronics is it's "voice tube".
With the Plantronics the mic is in the earpeace and the sound travels through a small
tube from your mouth to the mic. The tube is very small and does not get in the way.
This makes the headset really convenient to wear (huge difference to any other headset I tried).
You can place the tip of the tube very near your mouth and sound is excellent. I used to point it a little bit downwards to avoid hissing noises.

[image]
<sub>(source: [adcombhs.com](http://adcombhs.com/shopsite_sc/store/html/h251lg.jpg))</sub>

What I also like is that you can wear the Plantronics both sides, with the PC146 the mic is always on the left side (took me a while to get used to it, but not a big deal).

---

The PC146 is also a good headset. Unlike what you see in the picture, mine came with a pop filter.

[image]
<sub>(source: [adcombhs.com](http://adcombhs.com/shopsite_sc/store/html/sennheiser_pc146_usblrg.jpg))</sub>

I have mine connected via USB (but it also has 3.5 mm jacks) and the USB sound adapter is not very loud. Otherwise I have no real complaints with the PC146 either. It is just not nearly as convenient to wear as the Plantronics.